# No puedo acceder a las propiedades de un objecto pero si puedo mostrar en consola el objecto con sus respectivas propiedades

Tags: angular, angular7, angular6

En el service estoy llamando una API y esta me retorna correctamente un objecto de tipo ValidatorModel

```js
public checkEmail( userEmail: string) {
  return this.httpClient.post<ResponseModel<ValidatorModel>>(${this.apiRoot}${ENDPOINT.usercheckEmail},
  {email: userEmail});
}
```

Pero en Componente me suscribo a la peticion anterior, cuando intento ver el objecto que envia el service en la consola aparece correctamente pero cuando intento aceder a una propiedad de dicho objecto este dice que esta **undefined**

```js
emailExistValidator(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null {

  this.userService.checkEmail(control.value).subscribe(res =>
    {
      console.log(res.data);
      console.log(res.data.Message);
    }
  );
        return null;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el case es diferente `console.log(res.data.Message);` es `M` y en el log se ve que es `m`

Comment: Gracias efectivamente era eso!